# Passing state up from child component and call a function with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So this is my parent component - it's getting a state set from it's child component when what component is updated which works great

```
const [filteredCases, setFilteredCases] = useState([]);

<ChildComponent
  setFilteredCases={setFilteredCases}
/>
```

What I would like to do is also call a function whenever the setFilteredCases state is updated .. so something like this

```
const [filteredCases, setFilteredCases] = useState([]);

function foo() {
  // do things
}

<ChildComponent
  setFilteredCases={setFilteredCases, foo}
/>
```

But doing so seems to break the state update and never calls the function .. have I got the syntax wrong here or is there a better way to implement what I'm doing here?

Any advice / guidance / links to documentation welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using useEffect instead

```js
const [filteredCases, setFilteredCases] = useState([]);
const foo = () => {
  // some changes

}

useEffect(() => {
  // filteredCases has been updated
  foo();

}, [filteredCases]);


<
ChildComponent setFilteredCases = {
  setFilteredCases
}
/>

const ChildComponent = ({
  setFilteredCases
}) => {
  // Call the function this way:
  setFilteredCases([]);
  return (
    // Send out something.
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `state` or `method` as a props from parent to child component.

Example:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Another Example :

```
const [filteredCases, setFilteredCases] = useState([]);

function foo() {
  // do things
}

<ChildComponent
  setFilteredCases={setFilteredCases}
  foo={foo}
/>

const ChildComponent = ({ foo, setFilteredCases }) => {

  const onHandleClick = () => {
    // Call the functions
    setFilteredCases('value');
    foo();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={onHandleClick} >Click me</button>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```